# Toy R code on Bayesian inference for mean of a normal distribution [data of snowfall amount]

Tags: r, plot, statistics, bayesian, normal-distribution

I have a number of snowfall observations:

```
x <- c(98.044, 107.696, 146.050, 102.870, 131.318, 170.434, 84.836, 154.686,
       162.814, 101.854, 103.378, 16.256)
```

and I was told that it follows normal distribution with known standard deviation at 25.4 but unknown mean `mu`. I have to make inference on `mu` using Bayesian Formula.

This is information on prior of `mu`

```
mean of snow |  50.8  | 76.2  | 101.6 | 127.0 |  152.4 | 177.8  
---------------------------------------------------------------
probability  |   0.1  | 0.15  | 0.25  |0.25   |  0.15  |  0.1 
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

The following is what I have tried so far, but the final line about `post` does not work correctly. The resulting plot justs give a horizontal line.

```
library(LearnBayes)
midpts <- c(seq(50.8, 177.8, 30))
prob <- c(0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1)
p <- seq(50, 180, length = 40000)
histp <- histprior(p, midpts, prob)
plot(p, histp, type = "l")

# posterior density
post <- round(histp * dnorm(x, 115, 42) / sum(histp * dnorm(x, 115, 42)), 3)
plot(p, post, type = "l")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My first suggestion is, make sure you understand the statistics behind this. When I saw your

```
post <- round(histp * dnorm(x, 115, 42) / sum(histp * dnorm(x, 115, 42)), 3)
```

I reckoned you have messed up several concepts. This appears to be Bayes Formula, but you have wrong code for the likelihood. The correct likelihood function is

```
## likelihood function: `L(obs | mu)`
## standard error is known (to make problem easy) at 25.4
Lik <- function (obs, mu) prod(dnorm(obs, mu, 25.4))
```

Note, `mu` is a unknown, so it should be a variable of this function; also, likelihood is the product of all individual probability density at observations. Now, we can evaluate likelihood for example, at `mu = 100` by

```
Lik(x, 100)
# [1] 6.884842e-30
```

For successful R implementation, we need a vectorized version for function `Lik`. That is, a function that can evaluate on a vector input for `mu`, rather than just a scalar input. I will just use `sapply` for vectorization:

```
vecLik <- function (obs, mu) sapply(mu, Lik, obs = obs)
```

Let's try

```
vecLik(x, c(80, 90, 100))
# [1] 6.248416e-34 1.662366e-31 6.884842e-30
```

Now it is time to obtain prior distribution for `mu`. In principle this is a continuous function, but looks like we want a discrete approximation to it, using `histprior` from R package `LearnBayes`.

```
## prior distribution for `mu`: `prior(mu)`
midpts <- c(seq(50.8, 177.8, 30))
prob <- c(0.1, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1)
mu_grid <- seq(50, 180, length = 40000)  ## a grid of `mu` for discretization
library(LearnBayes)
prior_mu_grid <- histprior(mu_grid, midpts, prob)  ## discrete prior density
plot(mu_grid, prior_mu_grid, type = "l")
```

[image: prior distribution]

Before applying Baye's Formula, we first work out the normalizing constant `NC` on the denominator. This would be an integral of `Lik(obs | mu) * prior(mu)`. But as we have discrete approximation for `prior(mu)`, we use Riemann sum to approximate this integral.

```
delta <- mu_grid[2] - mu_grid[1]    ## division size
NC <- sum(vecLik(x, mu_grid) * prior_mu_grid * delta)    ## Riemann sum
# [1] 2.573673e-28
```

Great, all being ready, we can use Bayes Formula:

```
posterior(mu | obs) = Lik(obs | mu) * prior(mu) / NC
```

Again, as `prior(mu)` is discretized, `posterior(mu)` is discretized, too.

```
post_mu <- vecLik(x, mu_grid) * prior_mu_grid / NC
```

Haha, let's sketch posterior of `mu` to see the inference result:

```
plot(mu_grid, post_mu, type = "l")
```

[image: posterior density]

Wow, this is beautiful!!