# What does it mean to put an `rnorm` as an argument of another `rnorm` in R?

Tags: r, random, statistics, sampling

I have difficulty understanding what it means when an `rnorm` is used as one of the arguments of another `rnorm`? (I'll explain more below)

For example, below, in the first line of my R code I use an `rnorm()` and I call this `rnorm()`: `mu`.

`mu` consists of 10,000 `x`.

Now, let me put `mu` itself as the `mean` argument of a new `rnorm()` called "distribution".

My question is how `mu` which itself has 10,000 `x` be used as the `mean` argument of this new `rnorm()` called distribution?

P.S.: `mean` argument of any `normal distribution` can be a single number, and with only ONE single mean, we will have a single, complete normal. Now, how come, using 10,000 `mu` values still results in a single normal?

```
mu <- rnorm( 1e4 , 178 , 20 )         ;  plot( density(mu) )
distribution <- rnorm( 1e4 , mu , 1 ) ;  plot( density(distribution) )
```

Comment: i dont get it, `dim(matrix(mu))` is of dimension `10000X1`. What do you mean with 10000x and 10000y?

Comment: `rnorm(1, rnorm(1))` just uses a random number from the normal distribution as a mean for generating a new one. If you pass a vector of values to `rnorm`'s `mean` or 'sd` parameters, `?rnorm` tells you "_The numerical arguments other than n are recycled to the length of the result._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `distribution` is a **conditional density**. While the density you draw with `plot(density(distribution))`, is a **marginal density**.

Statistically speaking, you first have a normal random variable `mu ~ N(178, 20)`, then another random variable `y | mu ~ N(mu, 1)`. The plot you produce is the marginal density of `y`.

`P(y)`, is mathematically an integral of joint distribution `P(y | mu) * p(mu)`, integrating out `mu`.

> @李哲源ZheyuanLi, ahhh! so when we use a vetor as the mean argument or sd argument of an rnorm, the single, final plot is the result of the integral, right?

It means you are sampling from the marginal distribution. The density estimate approximates the Monte Carlo integral from samples.

---

This kind of thing is often seen in Bayesian computation. [Toy R code on Bayesian inference for mean of a normal distribution [data of snowfall amount]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40189329/4891738) gives a full example, but integral is computed by numerical integration.