# How to see Bayesian computations as clean matrices in R

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, normal-distribution

Given the clarity needed to understand how R can help doing Bayesian computations, in what follows, I will be asking R coding questions in this regard.

## some necessary details:

Suppose, I have an object called `mu`, defined as:

```
mu <- rnorm( 1e4 , 178 , 20 )         ## A vector of hypothesized values
```

The object `mu` is going to serve as the `mean` argument of the next object called `y.given.mu`:

```
y.given.mu <- rnorm( 1e4 , mu , 1 )   ## A vector of normal densities conditional on `mu`
```

## Question

I was wondering how I could:

**A)** cleanly see the matrix structure of `y.given.mu`?

**B)** multiply object `mu` by `y.given.mu` and cleanly see the matrix structure of the product of these two objects (i.e., joint distribution)

**C)** integrate out `mu` from **B)** so that I get `p(y)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed, we move all follow-up questions of your previous question [What does it mean to put an `rnorm` as an argument of another `rnorm` in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44121625/4891738) into another thread.

---

A reasonably sufficient grid

```
delta.mu <- 0.5    # this affects numerical integration precision
mu <- seq(178 - 3 * 20, 178 + 3 * 20, by = delta.mu)
delta.y <- 1    # this does not affect precision, by only plotting
y <- seq(min(mu) - 3, max(mu) + 3, by = delta.y)

# the range above is chosen using 3-sigma rule of normal distribution.
# normal distribution has near 0 density outside (3 * sd) range of its mean
```

Conditional density `p(y | mu)`

```
cond <- outer(y, mu, dnorm)
dimnames(cond) <- list(y = y, mu = mu)

# each column is a conditional density, conditioned on some `mu`
# you can view them by for example `plot(y, cond[, 1]), type = "l")
# you can view all of them by `matplot(y, cond, type = "l", lty = 2)`
```

Joint density `p(y, mu)`

```
# marginal of `mu`
p.mu <- dnorm(mu, 178, 20)
# multiply `p.mu` to `cond` column by column (i.e., column scaling)
joint <- cond * rep(p.mu, each = length(y))
```

Marginal density `p(y)`

```
# numerical integration by Simpson / Trapezoidal Rule
p.y <- rowSums(joint * delta.mu)
```

Now let's plot and check

```
plot(y, p.y, type = "l")
```